# How to resize the pictures right?

Tags: android

Hy!

I have two pictures on the view and a button at the buttom.

[image: Screenshot]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainscreen" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Selected Channel" android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainscreen_state" android:layout_above="@+id/mainscreen_btchange"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageAd" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/mainscreen"></ImageView> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainscreen_btchange" 
        android:text="Change State"></Button>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My Question: How to shrink the pictures that all elements of the layout are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complicated layouts where I need to ensure a bunch of items can all be displayed, I usually start with a RelativeLayout as my outermost container.  I dock whatever needs to be at the extremities with layout_alignParentTop and layout_alignParentBottom (in the case of vertical layouts, which yours seems to be), and then I work my in making the next set of elements relative to them.  Basically, start at the edges and work your way in.

So, in your case, the Button should have the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, and the TV should have `android:layout_above="@+id/mainscreen_btchange"`.  The TextView at the top should have `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and the ImageView underneath it should have `android:layout_below="@+id/mainscreen"`

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignBelow' in package 'android'

Comment: sorry...that's layout_above and layout_below.  I fixed the code sample as well

Comment: i want that the pictures are shown right. your code changed nothing with the pictures

Comment: what does "shown right" mean?  that's kind of vague.  My code helps you lay out the controls correctly so that the Button is no longer hidden from view.  Step 2 needs to be resizing the images properly to take up the right amount of available space, I assume.  This might require playing around with different containers.  Possibly have a LinearLayout in between the bottom and top elements (so, your layout_above and layout_below will both be on the same LinearLayout) and use layout_weight on the children to allow them to take up the appropriate amount of remaining space

Comment: updated the new xml. new screenshot : http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/p3ikxh61/device.png

Comment: You have the outermost element as a LinearLayout and the RelativeLayout only encompasses the Button.  You need to wrap the whole thing in the RelativeLayout for the elements to be positioned "relative" to each other.